# Google Chrome "resolving host" error on every DNS except OpenDNS

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome, dns

Pretty much what the title says. I'm running Windows 8 x64, using a USB wireless adapter.

Things I have tried

-ipconfig renew/release/flushndns plus system restart

-trying various DNS' (Google, etc.)

-different wireless adapters

It works fine with my ISP's DNS, which is OpenDNS. Thanks for the help, and sorry for any errors or any missing info.

Comment: Have you tried disabling IPv6? Seems to be a suggestion on the Google forums.

Comment: Just tried it. Didn't do anything.

Comment: Just to save a bit time reaming off a lot of text you might have tried, you might find your answer in here http://www.webnots.com/correct-chrome-resolving-host-issue.html

Comment: You don't describe what actions you perform to get the error. Does it occur when you go to every host every time?

Answer (score 2):

I had these problems for weeks using chrome on public wifi. I fixed it finally by disabling the "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" flag and now I have no problems. Type chrome://flags into the address bar and see all the chrome flags. Ctrl-F to search the page for "dns" and find the flag - disable it! Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro x64 on my desktop and had the same DNS problems with Chrome, even on a wired connection.  I updated the driver for my network adapter and all DNS errors went away.  It's been three weeks now and not a single problem.

Just another troubleshooting tip.